# any code coverage tools(statement, branch, MCDC) for QT C++ codes?

Tags: qt, unit-testing, automated-tests, code-coverage

I need to find the code coverage metrics values for my QT based GUI code. Please suggest any tool which would allow to create a test case and generate the coverage values.

Thanks,

Nayan

Comment: Request of tools, tutorials, libraries or similar are off-topic in SO. Please read the following for best questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I need feedback from the expert users regarding this and I feel the question is very clearly stated.

Comment: As I said your question is not correct for OS because it is off-topic, read the link I showed you.

Answer (score 0):

GCOV can be used to get statement and branch coverage

ref :[Qt and gcov, coverage files are not generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483370/qt-and-gcov-coverage-files-are-not-generated?rq=1)

other tool is TUG

ref:
http://pedromateo.github.io/tug_qt_unit_testing_fw/